# CSS Shadow Parts Selector ::part() does not work in combination with :disabled pseudo-class in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, shadow-dom

In Chrome, the pseudo-element selector `::part()` and additional `:disabled` pseudo-class does not work properly. This works in Firefox perfectly.

Here is a corresponding code snippet. Only in Firefox the disabled button will have a yellow background.

```js
customElements.define('my-button', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <button disabled part="button">Button in Shadow DOM</button>
    `;
  }
});
```

```css
my-button::part(button) {
  color: gray;
}

my-button::part(button):disabled {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<my-button></my-button>
```

Is this a Chrome-bug or intended behavior?

Comment: Good question for: https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues

Comment: Thanks. Done: https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/918

Answer (score 1):

[Per the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-shadow-parts-1/#part):

> The ::part() pseudo-element can take additional pseudo-classes after it, such as x-button::part(label):hover, but never matches the structural pseudo-classes or any other pseudo-classes that match based on tree information rather than local element information.
>
> The ::part() pseudo-element can also take additional pseudo-elements after it, such as x-button::part(label)::before, but never match additional ::part()s.

As `:disabled` isn't structural, this looks like a Chrome bug. After searching, [I found a bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=953648) on the Chromium bug tracker.